# JSON-API: why do we need to define an ID member when updating a resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, json-api

JSON-API spec [requires](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-updating) **id** member been defined when a resource is patched. But we still need to define a resource id inside a route. So, if one want to patch an article with id=1, a JSON object where defined an id member eq 1:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
   }
 }
```

needs to be send to http://example.com/articles/1 According to spec an id member is mandatory, but why do we need them both: in a resource link and inside a JSON object?